# How does EXPORT work?

Tags: command-line, unix, path, export

I tried to use export to set a PATH. But, I can not understand how it works?
This is my command:

```
export PATH=.:$PATH
```

So how it works? and What does PATH look like? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH variable is a special variable which contains a (in bash ":" separated) list of directories the shell will search in to find binaries.

The command you have issued instructs the shell to look in the current directory (".") before the other directories it already uses.

You can see what your PATH looks like with the command echo $PATH.
Mine looks like

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

The "export" statement means that any subcommands  or shells launched from this shell will inherit the changed path command.

Comment: It's very clearly and useful! Thank you so much!